# Destroying and creating a directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, frontend, angularjs-digest

I am very new to AngularJS(asynchronous paradigm of programming to be specific) and working on my first AngularJS project. I know the fundamentals and basic of it.
**Problem:** I have a directive which needs to be created only when I have the data, and the data is fetched asynchronously. Also, the directive is present in the controller's template. How should I go about it?
**My approach:** have a ng-if ="variable" on the directive that needs to be created once data is available, and have a watch on that variable, once the variable is set, the directive is created.
However, I am not able to do this programmatically! How can I achieve this or is there a better approach.

Controller

```
$scope.dataFeteched= false;
$http.get(url)
    .then(function success(result){
        $scope.dataFeteched = true;
    });
```

HTML

```
<span>Hello World</span>
<directive-abc ng-if="dataFeteched"></directive-abc>`
```

Also how would $digest execute that particular directive once it has already completed the execution of controller template?

Comment: it *feels like* you are trying too hard here.  In general, directives are already responsive to asynchronous data, and shouldn't need to be "delayed".  is there some reason that having the directive present in the DOM when there is no data is causing an issue?

Comment: the asynchronous data fetch code is in controller, and yes its an issue if the directive is present in the DOM.  this image might help you understand what i am doing [code design diagram](http://imgur.com/a/YvXWH)

Comment: what is that diagram supposed to show?  It definitely doesn't show any data, or why you have concerns.  Again, if a directive is properly designed, it should have no issue handling async data... that's one of the key tenants of angular, and one of the things that makes it so powerful.  You are asking here how to stop something built into the framework from happening naturally, and not explaining why you feel like you need to do this.

Comment: don't think about angular procedurally, think about it compositionally.  The angular digest cycle knows when the data it is watching has changed, and it adjusts the DOM to respond to these data changes.  Unless your directive is doing something extremely abnormal, it should be empty with no data, then present as data appears, without you needing to force your way around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can put directive inside html element and use ng-if on that element as below:
   `<div ng-if="dataFeteched"><directive-abc ></directive-abc></div>`

this will load directive if **datafetched** is true.

Answer (score 0):

See this example below.

Controller and Directive

```
app.controller('someCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    // intitially $scope.dataFetched is set to false
    $scope.dataFetched = false;
    $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
     .then(function(response){
        // some work based on response
        // upon callback set the $scope.dataFetched to true
        $scope.dataFetched = true;

  });
});
zapp.directive("someDirective", function() {
 return {
     template : "<h1>I am a directive!</h1>"
 };
});
```

And in HTML

```
<div ng-controller="someCtrl">
  <some-directive ng-show="dataFetched"></some-directive>
</div>
```

Now when you run this, it will show the directive only after return from http call. To test, you can comment out  `$scope.dataFetched = true;` inside the http call, and then uncomment it later.

Comment: it will load the directive. check applying debugger link function of directive.

Comment: Of course this will load the directive. But only after returning from the http call asynchronously. You can add conditions inside the callback and then load the directive. Which link are you talking about?

Comment: link function of directive. No your directive will load immediately the view load.